# How to hide all expand in controller side in asp.net mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller, expand

I make big project.So i have problem with expands.I Close expand however if there is exception , all expands opens automatily.

**I close expand one by one.So is there something to close all expands by easy way ?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cb0ec47d-05a4-40a7-ba39-9a2da6492f1c/